# How to convert output of 4digit BCD adder to hexadecimal

Tags: verilog

The output of 4digit BCD adder is "Cout" and "S[15:0]".

> {Cout,S} is the output of BCD adder.

How can i convert this into Hexadecimal.I have tried the following method but its not working

```
     reg  [19:0]temp,t; 
     temp={Cout,S};
     t[3:0]=temp%16;
     t[7:4]=(temp/16)%16;
     t[11:8]=(temp/256)%16;
     t[15:12]=(temp/4096)%16;
     t[19:16]=(temp/65536)%16;
     $display("t=%x",t);
```

but the value of "reg t" is coming in BCD only.

Comment: %16 *anything* gives a result [0,15]. Hex is comprised of 6 letters of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your BCD to binary by multiplying each digit by the appropriate power of 10 and summing. Now convert the binary number to hex.

By treating the Cout as a binary number, when you divide by 16 all you do is shift by four bits. When you then convert the 4 lsbs to hex, all you are doing is selecting the original digit.